# reqres.in returning other data (some collor values), (dart/http)

Tags: dart, http

http request in dart is returning different data from reqres.in, no free support provided.

Request with http package

```dart
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main(List<String> arguments) async {
  final url = Uri.https('reqres.in', '/api/users?page=2', {'page': '2'});
  var response = await http.get(url);
  //
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // print('Positive response');
    var jsonResponse =
        convert.jsonDecode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
    print(jsonResponse['data']);
  } else {
    print('something goes wrong');
  }
}
```

returns: //[{id:7,name: sand dollar, ...pantone_value:18-3943....

instead :

```json
 {
    "page": 2,
    "per_page": 6,
    "total": 12,
    "total_pages": 2,
    "data": [
    .....
```

Comment: Could you post a full minimal example that reproduces your issue? Because I can't seem to reproduce the issue with this code: https://gist.github.com/julemand101/f8ee0e36e1d36686a31823a290d13fc9

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, the method https returns unexpected values, with parse it works like expected, wondering why this behaviour.

https, unexpected response:

```
final url = Uri.https('reqres.in', '/api/users?page=2', {'page': '2'});
```

parse, the correct approach

```
Uri.parse('https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2');
```